# AWS Kedra to UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, uisearchbar, amazon-kendra

I am trying to merge the Aws Kendra search to my UI search bar but I am not knowing where to start can anybody please tell how can i do this.
I have been reading the amazon documents on how to create index for kendra and sync with the data source and also tried the hands on for the same.

I have already created a UI with html ,css and joined with javascript to send video files to s3 , now what I want to do is if any User searches any query or anything in the video should come as a result on the UI with using AWS kendra.

Comment: You have listed multiple specification requirements. What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to look at [Deploying Amazon Kendra](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kendra/latest/dg/deploying.html)? This page provides documentation on kick starting your Kendra integration with some starter code. Although this might be different than your current UI setup, it would cover how a website calls the Kendra backend on their Query APIs and process its Query results.

Comment: yeah i got it running there was a problem with my api and javascript code for getting data back.